# Docker and TexStudio: QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK

Tags: qt, docker, gtk

I'm attempting to dockerize TexStudio for a project, and while I can get the GUI to show up with the following, I also get the error 'QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the proper libraries.' I'm using the following to run this:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --name texstudio containername
```

Running some others (Netbeans, etc) just fine. The program does load, but the menu at the top is not displaying correctly (no padding between categories) and the dropdowns are empty. I'm fairly new to docker and to Linux in any real depth, but I'd assumed this was a problem displaying a Qt application.

If it matters, both the docker container and the machine are running ubuntu (16.04 and 15.04 respectively). Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, folks. I resolved it by installing libgnomeui-0 on the docker container. Now getting the error 'Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"' but at least it's something different. EDIT - I solved this error by installing libcanberra-gtk0.